# using axios in react, how to specify a time limit for a get request to error out?

Tags: reactjs, http, axios, frontend, fetch

If the server does not respond within `x` seconds, then I want to be counted as an error.

How to specify what `x` is using axios?

Comment: Is anything unclear from the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
// Create an instance using the config defaults provided by the library
// At this point the timeout config value is `0` as is the default for the library
const instance = axios.create();

// Override timeout default for the library
// Now all requests using this instance will wait 2.5 seconds before timing out
instance.defaults.timeout = 2500;

// Override timeout for this request as it's known to take a long time
instance.get('/longRequest', {
  timeout: 5000
});
```